# Options Object - Gmail API - Where is it Documented?

Tags: gmail-api

In the snippet of text below there is an Options Object.

Does anybody know where the options are documented?

I've tried searching here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

Cheers.

```
    $pageToken = NULL;
    $messages = array();

    // Options Object
    $optParam = [];
    $optParams['maxResults'] = 500; // Return Only 1 Message
    $optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox

    do {
        try {

            if ($pageToken) {
                $optParam['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }

            $messagesResponse = $this->service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', $optParam);

            if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
                $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
                $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

    } while ($pageToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all gmail api documentation here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've searched there. I can see a reference to "metadataHeaders" in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get but I can't find the list of what they are. Do you know where there is a list?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

You need to expand the box by clicking on the hash tag on "public Google_Service_Gmail_ListMessagesResponse".

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Gmail_UsersMessages_Resource.html

Also use this resource

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en-GB

With the query parameter.

For example:

```
$optParam['q'] = "after:2020/12/20";
```

You can test your queries in the Gmail search box.